# i get this error : Can't convert object of type java String to type com.example

Tags: java, android, string

Can't convert object to String. It looks like somewhere I have to convert these but i convert already in `HomeFragment`. I still get this error. I searched this on StackOverflow but noone's code or recommend couldn't fix that.

Comment: No need to post your full app code. Please post the error stack trace, it will tell the exact class and line number where the problem is.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? Please post your error logs

Comment: Its because you are parsing an object to string onDataChange. pass it to an object and after call object.the necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

    String cUID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Veriler").child(cUID);

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Users muser = dataSnapshot.child("sFirma").getValue(Users.class);
            Users mnewuser = new User();
            String sFirma = muser.getsFirma();
            String sServis= muser.getsServis();
            String sYakit= muser.getsYakit();
            String sNot= muser.getsNot();
            String nFirma= muser.getnFirma();
            String nAlici_firma= muser.getnAlici_firma();
            String nArac= muser.getnArac();
            String nYakit= muser.getnYakit();
            String nNot= muser.getnNot();
            String veri= muser.getveri();
            String zaman= muser.getzaman();
            mnewuser.setsFirma(sFirma);
         //set rest of your string in model as above
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

}
```

Comment: check wether you have data in that child node of firebase Realtime DB. Debug it and find their if their any values.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ go through the link and check how you can debug

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `onDataChange`method like below:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String sFirma = dataSnapshot.child("sFirma").getValue(Users.class);
            String sNot = dataSnapshot.child("sNot").getValue(Users.class);
            String sServis = dataSnapshot.child("sServis").getValue(Users.class);
            String sYakit = dataSnapshot.child("sYakit").getValue(Users.class);
            String veri = dataSnapshot.child("veri").getValue(Users.class);
            String zaman = dataSnapshot.child("zaman").getValue(Users.class);
            String nFirma = dataSnapshot.child("nFirma").getValue(Users.class);
            String nAlici_firma = dataSnapshot.child("nAlici_firma").getValue(Users.class);
            String nArac = dataSnapshot.child("nArac").getValue(Users.class);
            String nNot = dataSnapshot.child("nNot").getValue(Users.class);
            String nYakit = dataSnapshot.child("nYakit").getValue(Users.class);
}
```

Comment: I think you should put a break point inside your `onDataChange` and see what the exact structure is